# What happens to all the flesh that the walkers eat?

Tags: the-walking-dead, zombie

Well, I was watching *The Walking Dead* season 6, and during episode 1, when that walker bit

> Carter's face off,

I started to wonder!

What happens to all the flesh they consume?

Comment: I seem to recall a comment by the Governor's aide (with the glasses) while examining Michonne's zombie friends.  Something about how they were "slowly starving" due to her removing their jaws, making them unable to eat.  The implication i took from that is that Walking Dead zombies still have a need to eat, although significantly less than the living.  If they eat too much, presumably their bellies would burst and the contents would fall out =P